# Calculate area for each raster value within a polygons (python)

Tags: python, raster, polygonize, shape-area

I have a raster file and polygon shapefile. I need to calculate area for each raster value within a polygons.

Example: the polygon below Total area = 1000 ha. I need an area for each raster value in separate shapefile columns (more precise: 7 columns (as there are 7 unique values in raster). So:

shapefile['value0_area'] = 0 ha

shapefile['value1_area'] = 100 ha

shapefile['value3_area'] = 800 ha

shapefile['value4_area'] = 20 ha

shapefile['value6_area'] = 80 ha

shapefile['value7_area'] = 0 ha

The first thing I did was polygonize raster file, so that I could calculate the area. Not sure how to do that! Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want counts per polygon. You can rasterise each individual polygon and then count them.

I loop over the feature id (FID) field in OGR, but other possibilities are open.

```py
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import ogr

def do_stats_per_poly(raster_fname, vector_fname, ifeat,
                      sel_classes=None, nodata=200):
    """Calculates number of pixels in class  per polygon. Polygon
    is defined by featured ID `ifeat`, and you can either take all
    values (`sel_classes=None`) or just a list of the values you
    are interested in (`sel_classes=[89, 90]`). 
    Returns a dictionary of values:count.
    """
    poly = gdal.Warp("", raster_fname, format="MEM",
                    cutlineDSName=vector_fname,
                    cutlineWhere=f"FID={ifeat:d}",
                    cropToCutline=True, dstNodata=nodata
                    ).ReadAsArray()
    if sel_classes is None:
        sel_classes = np.unique(poly)
    retval = {}
    for c in sel_classes:
        retval[c] = np.sum(poly==c)
    return retval
    



vector_fname = "gadm36_ESP_2.shp"
raster_fname = "lc.tif"
# Figure out how many features ie polygons you have.
# Or set to a number if can't be bothered ;)
gg = ogr.Open(vector_fname)
n_feat = gg.GetLayerByIndex(0).GetFeatureCount()
stuff = []
for ifeat in range(n_feat):
    stuff.append(do_stats_per_poly(raster_fname, vector_fname, ifeat))
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the raster in QGIS. Run the tool Polygonize for this raster. On the output shapefile, calculate areas of each attribute. Then you can split (under Vector tools) this shapefile based on the attribute column (which says, 0 to 7 in this case). Your output files would be 7 shapefiles with areas.